# Return variable value based on user input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that takes a user's input and use it to call a specific vector without using a long `if` statement. For example, if a user were to input `"silver"`, I would like the program to call on the vector named `silver`. This way, the user can select a specific vector simply by typing a word in.

Is there any way to do this while avoiding `if` statements? My full program calls on lots of colors that the user inputs, and making `if` statements for all of them would be tedious.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cmath"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string color1;
    
    vector<double> gold = {0, 0, pow(10, -1), .95, 1.05};
    vector<double> silver = {0, 0, pow(10, -2), .9, 1.10};
    
    cout << "input color:";
    cin >> color1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear and your code is unnecessarily complicated. When you are trying to implement a new functionality, it behooves you to aim for the *simplest possible use* of that functionality. There's no reason to involve vectors -- or strings -- but if you want to avoid tedious `if` statements, I suggest you look into `std::map`.

Comment: @Beta I just updated the post to make it a little more clear. What should I use instead of strings or vectors?

Comment: @Pozu use [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), like Beta suggested. Use `std::string` as the key type, and `std::vector` as the value type.

Comment: FYI `pow(10, -2)` can be written as `1e-2`

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::map` as indicated in comments:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> m = {
    { "gold",   { 0, 0, pow(10, -1), .95, 1.05 } },
    { "silver", { 0, 0, pow(10, -2), .9,  1.10 } }
  };

  std::string color;

  std::cin >> color;

  std::cout << m[color][4] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Note that this does no checking to ensure the string input by the user is a key in the map.